# Getting URL parameters to spring mvc from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, url-parameters

I am trying to pass values to spring controller via URL. On angluar side i use *location* service to change URL:

```
$location.path('/somePage/' + data.id);
```

After that controller for *somePage* triggers:

```
$routeProvider.when('/somePage/:id'
```

That controller has a method which needs to fetch data from spring:

```
$scope.item = Service.findById($routeParams.id);
```

findById is in essence a http get:

```
findById: function() {
    return $http.get('/something/data/id');
}
```

On spring side i have a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/something/data")
public class Controller {
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
  public Data findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id);
  }
}
```

I can not get spring to fetch id parameter from URL. I am new to angularjs and spring so
any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you pass the id to the method findById? Shouldn't it look like that?

```
findById: function(id) {
    return $http.get('/something/data/' +id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your PathVariable import. It should be

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
```

but not

```
org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.PathVariable
```

Comment: import is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable